# Change material or color in mesh face

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have Three.Geometry object consisting of many vertexes and faces (grid). I want to dynamically change the color or material of selected face.

```
geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true; 
geometry.faces[1].color.setHex(0xcccccc);   //this doesn't work
```

Above code makes new color opacity weird. It behaves like it doesn't replace the color but blends new color with old. Therefore overwriting darker color with ligher is imposible. How to fix this ? My materials do apply :

`mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"white",shading: THREE.FlatShading,side: THREE.DoubleSide,vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,  needsUpdate : true});`

Another approach i wanted to do is also with changing the reference to other material:

```
geometry.faces[0].materialIndex = 1; // works only when disabled OpenGL in browser
```

Already  `set material.needsUpdate flag to true` 
and checked  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

still no change.

Comment: Can you provide a (simple) live example to demonstrate the unusual effect you are seeing?

Comment: OFC. Here is JsFiddle code - http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/1163/

Comment: AND here is zip version. It's better code than JsFiddle. I had to rewrite some stuff to make it work in JS fiddle. http://www.sendspace.com/file/ap1l4n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges. Do not use both face colors and `MeshFaceMaterial` simultaneously.

First of all, in WebGLRenderer, you can't change the face `materialIndex` after the mesh has been rendered once. You can change one of the materials in the material array, however.

You need to use `MeshBasicMaterial` for your mesh material, and specify `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors`. That way you can control each face color. Be sure to initial each face color so you get the checkerboard pattern. Also set the material color to `0xffffff`, otherwise you will see the multiplicative effect you are trying to avoid.

three.js r.58

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks. Wierd thou that it doesnt work the way i thought. I need some better explanation of how then multiple materials work. Such trivial problem took me 2 days :] lol